# How to troubleshoot serial communication?

Tags: usb, serial, uart

I connected my computer to a RM-BR300 controller to read its data, to try and mimic its functionality in the future.

I'm using RealTerm and a USB to RS422 converter for the job - here's the result:

[image: UART receiver framing error]

Sony's VISCA protocol says packets should start with an address like 0x80 and end with 0xFF.

**Why there are no visible packets in that sample?**

**What does the "UART receiver framing error" represent?**

[Here](http://www.vaddio.com/library?path=d&file=sony_h700_commandlist.pdf) is the list of commands that could be sent by this controller.

This image shows some info on the USB to Serial converter:

[image]

Comment: Usually it means that you have the bitrate wrong.

Comment: RS422 is twisted-pair, maybe the A and B lines got swapped on the receiver? With polarity inverted, mark is interpreted as space and vice versa, so instead of seeing 0x80 .. 0xFF you'd see 0xEF .. 0x00, except that the start/stop bits would be inverted polarity. So this would cause UART recevier framing errors.

Comment: If you are receiving a BREAK condition or error it is usually a result of setting your receiver bit rate much too high (and a long sequence of '0' bits is detected as a break) or a interface converter fault or misconfiguration, RS-485 compatible drivers sometimes need biasing resistors if they are not always driven when in RS-422 configuration, or idle conditions will look like a BREAK and data will be junk if the polarity is inverted, do not always trust labels, I have seen errors in one pair on some gear.

Comment: @KalleMP The RXTX info is written on the circuit itself. I've updated the question with a image from the manual. It appears to have a built in resistor, is that right?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @MarkU - I'm wiring RX- to TX- and RX+ to TX+ as is described everywhere. Is it safe to invert that wiring?

Comment: Make sure all of your flow control jumpers are disabled on that serial converter as well.

Comment: I agree with @MarkUon the inverted polarity guess. Seems to match the data-set well.  It should be fine to swap the differential pair + and - signals.  So instead, wire RX- to TX+, and RX+ to TX-.

Comment: The controller will start to send with 8X where X is 1 to 7 (slave addresses).  The slaves will start to reply with X0 where X is 9 to F (slave address + 8).  The standard bit rates are 9k6 and 38k4, try both.  When idle you should NEVER have BREAK (opposite of idle) error. Also consider ground references, if your RS-422 does not have a common ground you will have 5 to 15V of common mode range depending on equipment.  If they are isolated (optical/transformer) your compliance may be 500 to 1500V as long as there is a local ground connection.

Comment: The 120R termination resistor is required at each end of each data pair.  Bias resistors are only required if the transmitter is turned off by half duplex implementation and are not standard or often required (I design them in).  Check your system is jumpered for full duplex (4 wire) and flow controls off like justing wrote.  First try to connect a loopback to your self just to check the converter. You can also measure voltage across data pair (1 to 4 V is usual locally) if you send a BREAK the polarity should invert and your receiver window should show a BREAK error.

Comment: @MarkU You were right, both the receiver and transmitter have their polarities inverted. You might want to make that an answer.

Comment: @KalleMP I got it working by swapping both pairs. I couldn't believe when you said the data would be junk if the polarity was inverted - I was trying to fix the data earlier by flipping and changing the bit order (in java), it appears to be impossible to programmatically recover from an inverted polarity case? Thanks a lot for the detailed info.